# Access a log file generated by .NET Core Console Application inside Docker

Tags: docker, logging, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm completely new to the Docker world and no matter where ever I searched for it, it seems like there's no applicable solution. I know many questions asks about the same issue surrounding logging, yet I could not find a basic, detailed solution that will help me to apply it myself.

**tldr;**

I currently have a .NET Core 5.0 Console Application that creates a log file using `log4net` to a local directory. I want to transfer the application to run through a `Windows-based` docker container and to access the `log` file while/after it ran to see its results.

I saw the [docker documentation | volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) yet could not understand how is it possible to define and later on access the log file.

Is this the way to do it? what should I define differently on my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's not about changing anything in your application, you just need to identify the directory where your logs are stored in the container and attach a volume or bind a mount to it on the host part. So, you can either:

- Create a volume and during "docker run" associate it with a directory inside the container where your logs are stored. Volumes can be managed using Docker, which makes it a preferred option. By leveraging them you can e.g. type "docker inspect some-volume-name" to find out where in the host's file system you can see the files from the volume, your logs in this case.
- Make a bind mount, which means you are mapping a directory from a host to a directory in a container. This option is pretty straightforward, but you are losing out on all the volumes' features.

**Path with volume**

Creating a docker volume.

```
docker volume create logs-from-net-app
```

Inspecting the volume to find out where you can find its contents.

```
docker volume inspect logs-from-net-app
```

Attaching it to the container.

```
docker run --mount type=volume,source=logs-from-net-app,target=//c/path/to/logs "hello-world"
```

**Path with mounting bind**

Making a bind mount during docker run

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=C:\logs,target=//c/path/to/logs "hello-world"
```

Comment: Thank you! This comment was a great jump to my understanding of Docker and basically provided the exact answer I needed.